# Default constructor issue declaring values

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class Employee {

     public  Employee(){
        id=-1;
        year=-1;
        salary=-1; 
        name="NA";
        department="NA"; 
    }

    public  Employee(int id ,String name ,String department, int year,double salary){
        String s="Sales";
        String i="IT";
        String W="Warehouse";
        if(department.equals(W)) {
            this.department=department;}
        else 
            if(department.equals(s)) {
                this.department=department;}
            else 
                if(department.equals(i)) {
                    this.department=department;}
                else 
                    System.out.print("Department was not set"); 
    }
```

main

```
int input,id ,year ;
double salary;
String name ,department; 

System.out.print("Enter Employee 1 details (id, name, department, years, salary)");
id=kb.nextInt(); 
name=kb.next(); 
department=kb.next();
year=kb.nextInt(); 
salary=kb.nextDouble();  
Employee Employee=new Employee(id, name, department, year, salary);
```

My issue is I declared values in the default constructor that set

```
id=-1;
year=-1;
salary=-1; 
name="NA";
department="NA";
```

But when the user enters invalid values it prints null or 0

I tried using

```
Employee Employee=new Employee();
Employee=new Employee(id, name, department, year, salary);
```

but it the same prints `null` or `0`. Any ideas where is the issue

Comment: You have _more than one constructor_.

Comment: Do you assign the arguments to the class variables ? `public  Employee(int id ,String name ,String department, int year,double salary){this.id=id;this.name=name;  ........}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a call to the default constructor from your all-argument constructor.

```
public Employee(int id, String name, String department, int year, double salary) {
    this();
    // the rest

}
```

The problem is

```
new Employee()
```

and

```
new Employee(id, name, department, year, salary)
```

are independent and the latter sets only one `department` field, while you want them all to be set.

```
 this();
```

would mean "populate with the default values first".

This constructor

```
 Employee(int id, String name, String department, int year, double salary)
```

is also an issue. It takes a lot of arguments but works with one. Consider setting them

```
this.id = id;
// and others
```

The validation condition could be simplified

```
if (department.equals(W) || department.equals(s) || department.equals(i)) {
    this.department = department;
} else {
    // a message or exception 
}
```

Comment: Usually this is done the other way around. A constructor with fewer parameters calls a constructor with more parameters and passes default values, i.e. `this(-1, "NA", "NA", -1, -1)`